# Query mongoose to find all JSON objects matching "req.body.search"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a search box that I want to return any JSON Object matching the search using mongoose.

Right now I can only search for the name of the object which then return a JSON object matching the searched name.:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var App = mongoose.model('App');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var exp = express();

exp.use(bodyParser.json()); 
exp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})); 


module.exports.searchApp = function(req, res) {
  App.findOne({
    'app_name': req.body.search
  }).exec(function(err, app) {
    res.status(200);
    res.json(app);
  });
};
```

How do I compose a query that will return  any JSON Object matching the search using mongoose?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a query term and a few JSON objects you would expect to get back?

Comment: "app_id": 1,
    "app_name": "Sonsing",
    "app_developer": "Skynoodle",
    "app_version": "2.8",
    "price": 16
},
    {
        "app_id": 2,
        "app_name": "Fintone",
        "app_developer": "Trupe",
        "app_version": "0.8.9",
        "price": 9
    },
    {
        "app_id": 3,
        "app_name": "Overhold",
        "app_developer": "Tagopia",
        "app_version": "6.31",
        "price": 58
    },

Comment: Use `find` instead of `findOne`

Comment: These objects are generated apps. I want to be alse to query mongoose to give me back the objects matching either app_developer || app_version || price.

Comment: Please edit your question with an example to enlighten us with what you expect to receive. Also, place a query sample please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongo's FTS functionality to search into more than one fields:

First, you have to create a few [text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/) for the fields you would like to include into your search.

Then using the [text operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) you will do a query with a search term and Mongo will search for that term into the text indexes you've specified above.

```
App.find({
   $text: {
      $search: req.body.search
   }
})
```